# Apache Ant Configuration Not Working

Tags: java, ant

I am new for Apache ant and have downloaded it and want to automate some task

I have already configured Ant_Home in System Environment. When i an running Ant in prompt it shows me following error:

```
C:\>ant
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

C:\>
```

Comment: Sorry but I've got to ask. Do you have a build.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ant wants (by default) a build.xml file that specifies the tasks to accomplish. use

```
c:\> ant -help
```

to know the syntax of the ant command appropriate for your case ... and figure out the build.xml appropriate for your project. Your installation seems to work :) ... that message is from ant.